# assert() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php

I'm passing two parameters to `assert` function as it's stated on PHP tutorial site, and get the error. Here is how I do it:

```
assert('2 < 1', 'Two is less than one');
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: [You're welcome](http://3v4l.org/7SGdl)

Comment: why was this downvoted? is the answer so obvious? I cannot conceive they changed the API of such a basic utility in a minor version of 5.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not on php 5.4.8 you can still get meaningful messages by putting a comment in the first assert argument:

```
$x = 1; $y = 2;
assert('$x > $y /*x should be greater than y*/');
```

This gives the output:

```
Warning: assert(): Assertion "$x > $y /*x should be greater than y*/" failed in ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The extra second parameter was added to the `assert` method in PHP 5.4.8. If you're using an older version than that, you must use only one parameter.

Source: http://php.net/assert

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP Version 5.3.13. It can't be configured even with `assert_options`?

Comment: no, you must follow the API for the version of PHP you are using.

Comment: but I can specify callback, right, which can produсe the output string?

Comment: You can set a callback method for *all* failed assertions, yes. It would require serious nuttiness to use this to set a custom message for every assertion in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The assert description parameter wasn't added until php version 5.4.8, what version of php are you using?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php

Answer (score 0):

you should use the options, here is the working example:

```
// Active assert and make it quiet
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1);

// Create a handler function
function my_assert_handler($file, $line, $code, $desc = null)
{
    echo "Assertion failed at $file:$line: $code";
    if ($desc) {
        echo ": $desc";
    }
    echo "\n";
}

// Set up the callback
assert_options(ASSERT_CALLBACK, 'my_assert_handler');

// Make an assertion that should fail
assert('2 < 1');
assert('2 < 1', 'Two is less than one');
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't address why the OP is getting the error `assert() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`. See [*sevenseacat*'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19466442/1438393).